# getting a specific value using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm working on windows 8 metro apps and i need to get some information from a XML file.
i parse it with LINQ to XML but I've got a problem.
here is the XML:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.allocine.net/v6/ns/">
  <page>1</page>
  <count>1</count>
  <results type="movie">10</results>
  <results type="person">0</results>
  <totalResults>10</totalResults>
  <movie code="61282">
    <originalTitle>Avatar</originalTitle>
    <title>Avatar</title>
    <productionYear>2009</productionYear>
    <release>
      <releaseDate>2010-09-01</releaseDate>
    </release>
    <castingShort>
      <directors>James Cameron</directors>
      <actors>Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang, Michelle Rodriguez</actors>
    </castingShort>
    <statistics>
      <pressRating>4.33333</pressRating>
      <userRating>4.31338</userRating>
    </statistics>
    <poster path="/medias/nmedia/18/78/95/70/19485155.jpg" 
            href="http://images.allocine.fr/medias/nmedia/18/78/95/70/19485155.jpg"/>
    <linkList>
      <link rel="aco:web" 
            href="http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=61282.html"/>
    </linkList>
  </movie>
</feed>
```

I need to get "code" value of the "movie" node and the "href" value of the node "link" but all the things i tried failed  ...

You can consider that the beginning of the XML is `<movie>` because I get the file and i parse it to keep the XML clean as I want. my file start with `<movie code="">`

For a classic value like "actors" i do :

```
Actors = (string)query.Element("castingShort").Element("actors")
```

It is working perfectly! My problem is for the specific value with a name.

edit :

that's what i did with your advices.

```
        var group1 = new SampleDataGroup("Group-1", "Films", "", "Assets/icone_groupe_all_movies.jpg", "Films sur le DD");
        movieName = "avatar";
        Uri = "http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/search?partner=YW5kcm9pZC12M3M&filter=movie,person&count=1&page=1&q=" + movieName + "&format=xml";
        var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(Uri);
        string sourceCode = get_new_xml(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sourceCode);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.allocine.net/v6/ns/";
        XElement movie = doc.Root.Element(ns + "movie");
        XElement castingShort = movie.Element(ns + "castingShort");
        XElement statistics = movie.Element(ns + "statistics");
        Data data = new Data
        {
            MovieCode = (string)movie.Attribute("code"),
            OriginalTitle = (string)movie.Element(ns + "originalTitle"),
            Title = (string)movie.Element(ns + "title"),
            ProductionYear = (string)movie.Element(ns + "productionYear"),
            Directors = (string)castingShort.Element(ns + "directors"),
            Actors = (string)castingShort.Element(ns + "actors"),
            PressRating = (string)statistics.Element(ns + "pressRating"),
            UserRating = (string)statistics.Element(ns + "userRating"),
            Cover = (string)movie.Element(ns + "linkList").Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href")
        };
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-1", data.Title, data.Cover, data.ProductionYear, "", data.ReleaseDate, group1));
        this.AllGroups.Add(group1);
```

but unfortunately it still doesent work ...

Answer (score 3):

Thus you have namespace declared in your xml, you should declare and initialize an XNamespace object, and to use it when specifying XName objects (arguments to Element methods):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XNamespace ns =  "http://www.allocine.net/v6/ns/";
XElement movie = xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "movie");
var code = (int)movie.Attribute("code");
var href = (string)movie.Element(ns + "linkList")
                        .Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href");
```

---

If you have only one `<movie>` element, then you don't need to operate on sequence of movie elements and treat single movie as list. Simply get `movie` node and create new data object via parsing that node:

```
XNamespace ns =  "http://www.allocine.net/v6/ns/";
XElement movie = xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "movie");
XElement castingShort = movie.Element(ns + "castingShort");
XElement statistics = movie.Element(ns + "statistics");
Data data = new Data
{
    MovieCode = (int)movie.Attribute("code"),
    OriginalTitle = (string)movie.Element(ns + "originalTitle"),
    Title = (string)movie.Element(ns + "title"),
    ProductionYear = (string)movie.Element(ns + "productionYear"),
    Directors = (string)castingShort.Element(ns + "directors"),
    Actors = (string)castingShort.Element(ns + "actors"),
    PressRating = (string)statistics.Element(ns + "pressRating"),
    UserRating = (string)statistics.Element(ns + "userRating"),
    Cover = (string)movie.Element(ns + "linkList")
                         .Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href") 
};
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, for the href it's working perfectly but it's not for the code. i don't understand why you did a new variable called ns and another one called movie ... can you explain please cause when i'm doing it, its not working

Comment: @bottus just verified - it gives me `61282` for movie code. Maybe you have changed something - set a breakpoint and verify what value of movie element you have.

Comment: @bottus see [working with namespaces in xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943852.aspx). Also I introduced `movie` variable just to make querying more simple (thus both queries need to get movie element).

Comment: that's what i did : http://nsa31.casimages.com/img/2012/12/21/121221010432466530.png         when i set "MovieCode = (int)movie.Attribute("code")," as comment, my apps is working but when i let the line in the code without the comment, it's not

Comment: @bottus do you have several `movie` nodes in your xml? I see only single movie node in sample you provided

Comment: there is always just one ;)

Comment: hey mate, thanks for answering, i edit my first post to show you wha i did ;)

Comment: @bottus unfortunately I still not know what `it doesent work` means. Have you tried setting breakpoint, as I recommended to you? Btw editing a question is a not very good idea

Comment: XElement movie = doc.Root.Element(ns + "movie");
XElement castingShort = movie.Element(ns + "castingShort"        XElement statistics = movie.Element(ns + "statistics");                    i set a breakpoint at these lines and movie, castingShort and statistics are NULL ...

Comment: @bottus then your xml is not same as you provided in question, verify what string you receive from server

Comment: okay at the begining i told you that my xml start with the node movie and not feed, but right now without the parsing which give me the "new xml" it is working perfectly !!! thanks so much for your time lazyberezovsky !!